# Orthorectification with R

Tags: raster, r, orthophoto, orthorectification

How can I orthorectify an oblique image of a flat landscape when I know the conditions of the photo (coords, height, direction, lens, etc)?

I would like to perform this kind of stuff from [GRASS orthorectification](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Orthorectification_digital_camera#Ortho-rectification_of_oblique_photographs) but in R.

Comment: The thing here is that I can't find any library to do this kind of things.

Comment: Is calling GRASS functions from R acceptable? Because that interface exists.

Comment: Could you please share some guide to use GRASS from R ?